# Can compile script form GitHub

Tags: gcc, compilation, cgo

Can compile script from this [link](https://github.com/strasharo/RouterScan-console). I very need to use this script in linux. But, I have problem with compiling, when start Makefile get this exceptions:

```
./Makefile: 1: build:: not found
# github.com/dilap54/RouterScan-console/cmd/cli
/usr/lib/go-1.19/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-2422249306/000019.o:/home/adminas/Downloads/RouterScan-console/pkg/librouter/liblibrouter.h:84: multiple definition of `globalArgs'; /tmp/go-link-2422249306/000018.o:/home/adminas/Downloads/RouterScan-console/pkg/librouter/liblibrouter.h:84: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-2422249306/000019.o:/home/adminas/Downloads/RouterScan-console/pkg/librouter/liblibrouter.h:75: multiple definition of `GetParam_DWord'; /tmp/go-link-2422249306/000018.o:/home/adminas/Downloads/RouterScan-console/pkg/librouter/liblibrouter.h:75: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-2422249306/000019.o:/home/adminas/Downloads/RouterScan-console/pkg/librouter/liblibrouter.h:73: multiple definition of `IsRouterStopping'; /tmp/go-link-2422249306/000018.o:/home/adminas/Downloads/RouterScan-console/pkg/librouter/liblibrouter.h:73: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /home/adminas/Downloads/RouterScan-console/pkg/librouter/liblibrouter.so: undefined reference to `MD5@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Maybe someone, have 100% working script routerscan in linux?

Try to update cgo, gcc

Comment: Try reinstal go - don't help :(